# Perl regex doesn't split string as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I have a use case where I want to extract the second of from a string using a regex in Perl.

I wrote a simple test string and ran a simple regex against it but received weird results:

```
my $s     = 'sip:255:255.255.255:8080;transport=TCP 5.6.7.8:aaaa 99.99.9.9aaaa8.8.8.7';
my (@ips) = $s =~ /((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/g;

print "$ips[0]\n";
print "$ips[1]\n";
print "$ips[2]\n";
```

I would have expected to get

```
5.6.7.8
99.99.9.9
8.8.8.7
```

but instead I get:

```
5.6.7.8
7.
99.99.9.9
```

As if the second result is actually part of the first IP. Can anyone spot what is wrong here?

Comment: You have two capturing groups. Try changing the inner group from `(\d{1,3}\.)` to `(?:\d{1,3}\.)`. That is, add an `?:` (no capture) marker immediately after the second `(` in your regex.

Comment: @DanBron this helped. A capturing group is defined by parenthesis? i.e. regardless of the entire regex rule. each element located inside a parenthesis will be matched by its own?

Comment: That's too long a discussion to have here in full, but yes, each set of parentheses, otherwise unqualified, will produce a capture group. Like `my ($first_name, $last_name) = $name =~ /(\w+) (\w+)/`. This applies even if the parentheses are nested. The only way to turn it off is to qualify the group somehow. All grouping qualifiers start with a `?` immediately after the `(`. The simplest is `?:` for "don't capture, just group". But there are others, like negative lookarounds (as with the `?!` in Kira's answer), which by definition don't match anything at all.

Comment: @DanBron: Well said. Please write this up as an answer. Your last comment with some added layout should mostly suffice. Note, however, that *"The only way to turn it off is to qualify the group"* is incorrect. Perl v5.22 introduced the `/n` modifier which disables all captures, so `$s =~ /((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/ng` will also work (although the outer parentheses are unnecessary).

Comment: @Anton.P: You may have understood better if you had examined all the contents of `@ips` (`print "$_\n" for @ips`) instead of assuming there were only three elements. Also, did you mean to put a colon `:` in `255:255.255.255:8080`?

Answer (score -1):

You have two captures, so two values are returned per match. Replace the needless capture

```
/((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/g
```

You might want to make sure the preceding and following characters aren't digits (so you don't match `1111.222.333.4444`), and you might want to limit yourself to matching ASCII digits (`0` to `9` rather than the 370 chars `\d` normally matches).

```
/(?<![0-9])((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})(?![0-9])/g
```

or

```
/(?<!\d)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?!\d)/aag
```